# Prove between Simson line & Nine point circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Prove that the Simson lines of diametrically opposite points on the circumcircle are perpendicular to each other and meet on the nine-point circle.

I proved the first part of the problem but not able to prove second part, please provide the proof of second part.

For the prove of first part:

**Lemma**:

*Angle between Simson line is half the angular measure of the arc between the point (on circumcircle).*

Hence angular measure of the arc = $180$ so it directly follows from this lemma.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part you can use the following lemmas:

**Lemma 1.** Simson line of point $P$ bisects segment $PH$, where $H$ is the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$.

**Lemma 2.** Nine-point circle is the image of circumcircle in the homothety with center $H$ and scale $\frac 12$.